# Finding the allowed values of the total angular momentum $j$ and the projection of total angular momentum $m_{j}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

If I have an atom that is in state $l=2$ with spin $s= \frac{1}{2}$, I am trying to obtain the allowed values for the total angular momentum quantum number $j$ and for each allowed value of $j$, the values of the projections of $j$.

I understand that to find $j$, I use:

$$j = l+s, ..., |l-s|$$ in steps of $1$.

I arrive at: $$j = \frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$$

However, I am unsure how to obtain the allowed values of the projection $m_{j}$ for *each* value of $j$.

Comment: Your values of $j$ are not correct. Surely $l+s=5/2$...  Once you have the $j$'s the m's follow as they run from $-j$ to $j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually one usually first finds the complete list of values of $m_l+m_s$: since the total projection $L_z=L_{z1}+L_{z2}$, you will have
\begin{align}
L_z\left[\vert 2m_l\rangle\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}m_s\rangle\right]&=
\left[L_{z1}\vert 2m_l\rangle\right] \vert \textstyle{\frac{1}{2}}m_s\rangle
+\vert 2m_l\rangle\vert \left[L_{z2}\vert \frac{1}{2}m_s\rangle\right]\, ,\\
&=(m_l+m_s)\vert 2m_l\rangle\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}m_s\rangle\, .
\end{align}

As the values of $m_j$ must run from $-j$ to $j$ and *all values of $m_j$ must appear* for a given $j$, one can deduce the possible values of $j$ recursively:

1. Look first at the largest value $m_l+m_s$ in the list of all the possible $m_j$'s.  This value must be the largest $j$, removing one copy of all $m_j$ values between $m_l+m_s$ and $-(m_l+m_s)$.  Having removed these $m_j$'s we get an updated list of remaining values of $m_l+m_s$.
2. Repeat the process with the updated list.
3. Repeat step 2 until all values of $m_l+m_s$ are exhausted.